# Filtering Model formsets

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

First try at playing with [model formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) with django and was wondering how to filter by the logged in user.  The view below renders a form with all the profiles when I only want them to list one (the user's one).

```
def create_profile(request):
   ProfileFormSet = modelformset_factory(Profile)
   if request.method == 'POST':
       formset = ProfileFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if formset.is_valid():
           instances = formset.save()
    else:
        formset = ProfileFormSet()
return render_to_response('create_profile.html', {'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one, why are you using formsets at all? You just need a standard [modelform](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: And this is why I shouldn't try to code when hungover!  Thanks.